# Backporting bytearray to Python 2.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, arrays, python-2.5

I'm trying to convert [this](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server) websocket example for use in Python 2.5, but am running into errors with the use of the bytearray type.

The code stops working for Python 2.5 here (in the send_text method of [websocket_server/websocket_server.py](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server/blob/master/websocket_server/websocket_server.py)):

```
    FIN    = 0x80
    OPCODE = 0x0f
    def send_text(self, message):
       header = bytearray();
       payload = encode_to_UTF8(message)
       payload_length = len(payload)
       header.append(FIN | OPCODE_TEXT)
       header.append(payload_length)

       self.request.send(header + payload)
```

The message variable stores the string input that is sent to clients.

It attempts to create an array of bytes and send that using the self.request.send method. How would I change this to make it work in Python 2.5 which doesn't have the bytes type or bytearray?

Comment: What's the reason to using Python 2.5 instead of upgrading?

Comment: The library I'm developing on is currently running Jython 2.5.3.

Comment: Yes, Jython 2.5.3 has struct

Comment: Then, instead of using bytearray, use `struct.pack` to create your header + payload. That way you create a binary package of your data, I hope that works.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, would the syntax look like 

struct.pack(fmt, FIN | OPCODE_TEXT, payload_length)
and then self.request.send(struct + payload).

Is that correct? What should the fmt parameter be?

Comment: I'll just write an answer with a possible guidance for you solve your prroblem using struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using struct MIGHT work, I haven't tested this.

What I would do, as a workaround, would be to use struct.pack to pack byte by byte.

```
mensaje = "saludo"
FIN    = 0x80
OPCODE = 0x0f
payload = ''
for c in mensaje:
    payload += struct.pack("H", ord(c))

msj = struct.pack("H",FIN | OPCODE )
msj+= struct.pack("H",len(payload))
print msj + payload
```

I'm using "H" as the 'fmt' parameter in the struct.pack function, but you better check how is your package sent and how many bytes per 'character' (since I'm guessing you're using unicode, I'm using 'H', unsigned short = 2 bytes).

More info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html, section 7.3.2.1 and 7.3.2.2.

EDIT: 
I'll answer here, what do I mean by using 'chr()' instead of 'struct.pack()':

```
mensaje = "saludo"
FIN    = 0x80
OPCODE = 0x0f
payload = mensaje
msj = chr( FIN | OPCODE )
msj+= chr(len(payload))
print msj + payload
```

if you print the message, then you should see the same output when using `struct.pack("B", ord(something))` than when using `ord(something)`, I just used struct.pack() because I thought your message was two bytes per char (as unicode).

Comment: Thank you so much! This workaround worked using fmt = "B" instead of "H". It looks like the server is able to send text now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. So, you're sending ascii bytes? (B is one char, in that case instead of struct you could just use `ord(c)`

Comment: Yes it looks like I'm sending ascii bytes. What do you mean by replacing struct with ord(c)?

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe that code (with no `struct.pack()` function) works as well. --> OK, it was 'chr' not 'ord'. Check the last edition.

Comment: That works as well! Can you explain why this (and/or struct) works as a replacement to bytearray?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, bytearray is just a sequence of bytes. A string is also a sequence of bytes. What `struct.pack`does is storing bytes in a string in an easy way. So, as you see, since all the options are just an array of bytes, then they all just behave the same. Of course, in this case is easy since we're talking of one byte characters, but with unicode I guess the use os struct.pack() is necessary (which is just a way of packing bytes in a tring array ... the same than bytearray).